# HTML5 Navigation processing model--

Tags: javascript, html, performance

the last two steps, load event start and load event end,

I am confused with these two. loadEventStart vs. domContentLoadedEventStart

For the first one (loadEventStart), what kind of the events in this step need to be loaded?

I thought all things will get loaded at domContentLoadedEventEnd.

Can anyone explain this please?

---

To be clear, I dont understand what loadEventStart really does.

What is the different between this one and domContentLoadedEventStart?

Comment: "last two steps" where? cite your sources. What are you trying to achieve? What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document's `load` event will be called once all resources (CSS, JS, images etc) referenced on the page are loaded. `DOMContentLoaded` will be called once the browser has parsed the document's DOM tree, and therefore will be called before `load`.